# Django's HttpResponseRedirect is http instead of https

Tags: django, redirect, nginx, https

My server runs Django + Gunicorn + nginx.

I have added an SSL certificate and configured nginx to redirect http to https. When an https request is received, nginx passes it to Gunicorn as http.

My program sometimes returns `HttpResponseRedirect`, and the browser gets a redirect response and re-requests as http, so nginx redirects to https.

How can I avoid this? How can I configure the server so that the first redirection points directly to an https URL?

Comment: I actually do the same thing. Tell Nginx to redirect all http request to https and it's working pretty fine.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the nginx configuration (inside the `location` block), specify this:

```
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

The `proxy_redirect` tells nginx that, if the backend returns an HTTP redirect, it should leave it as is. By default, nginx assumes the backend is stupid and tries to be smart; if the backend returns an HTTP redirect that says "redirect to http://localhost:8000/somewhere", nginx replaces it with something similar to http://yourowndomain.com/somewhere". But Django isn't stupid (or it can be configured to not be stupid).

Django does not know whether the request has been made through HTTPS or plain HTTP; nginx knows that, but the request it subsequently makes to the Django backend is always plain HTTP. We tell nginx to pass this information with the `X-Forwarded-Proto` HTTP header, so that related Django functionality such as `request.is_secure()` works properly. You will also need to set `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')` in your `settings.py`.

Comment: Do i need to set both nginx and django ,or just set nginx?

Comment: I'm not certain what you mean. Your best bet would be to have django return redirections as a relative url, that is "/target" rather than "http://domain/target".

Comment: I mean after I set nginx as what you said, do I also need to set django settings.py or its just a improve for other functions. After all, you answer really helps ,thanks!

Comment: @permike I thought this might be useful to more people so I blogged about it at https://djangodeployment.com/2017/01/24/fix-djangos-https-redirects-nginx/.

Comment: @AntonisChristofides I've tried exactly as you describe, but in my request it shows HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO = 'http,http'. Any ideas what could be going on here?  Everything else shows as being https, including the URL.

Comment: @Alex No ideas, but you need to be very precise. Your request doesn't "show" anything, and I don't believe there's any `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO = 'http,http'` anywhere verbatim. While I suspect that you mean that the request includes the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` header with the value `http,http`, we shouldn't be working on suspicion or conjecture when we can have the facts. If you phrase it accurately you are likely to find the solution yourself.