# HSTS and HTTPS settings Invalid

Tags: django-2.1

I set several settings as django document said, but i got two problem:

1. `SecurityMiddleware` didn't work
2. once `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True` website will can't  be visited

`SecurityMiddleware` supposed to set `Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains` is responde header, but i check by chrome F12 , response header is like that:

```
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 13 Jun 2019 02:18:17 GMT
Server: openresty/1.15.8.1
Set-Cookie: uid=e59e2b54f7d64a6799b0f160dc80fae6; expires=Sun, 10 Jun 2029 02:18:17 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=315360000; Path=/
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

no Strict-Transport-Security in it

i use nginx to redirect , but i still wondering why `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True` cause website unavliabe to visit, and if this setting has other affect?
chrome shows `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

django settings:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
   # 'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'blog.middleware.user_id.UserIDMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.xxxxxx.club']

#SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 31536000
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = True
```

Comment: You don't set your cookies to secure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figure this two problems out, two problems caused by same reason.
i use nginx as proxy and set redirery HTTP to HTTPS in nginx, but

> the proxy may be “swallowing” the fact that a request is HTTPS, using a non-HTTPS connection between the proxy and Django

so django always get HTTP request, while setting `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True` all http redirect to HTTPS, but all these HTTPS will again became http between the proxy and Django, that is the reason cause infinity redirect.

if `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False` django won't redirect http from nginx, and django will only set `strict-transport-security` in HTTPS response header, that why even though my browser receive https response (by nginx, no django), no `strict-transport-security` in response header
so i changed some settings:

1. set `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')` in django settings
2. set `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;` in location inside 443 port of nginx conf

https://github.com/richardcornish/django-removewww/issues/1
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41488430/11350098

Comment: I head infinite redirects on daphne (too many redirects). Setting SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True was the reason making an issue with nginx. But I have set SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https') instead, as you suggested and it works now. Thanks! Great solution.