# Too many redirects on nginx and django applicaiton.Redirecting all http request to https in django, nginx, uwsgi

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi, nginx-config, system-administration

I'm working on legacy code and trying to configure nginx and ssl certificate of the django based application as I'm not a system adminstrator but I'm trying. I have searched and tried almost all answers on stackoverflow and in the internet but I couldn't solve it. Here nginx configuration file is located on sites-enabled folder not sites-available. nginx version is 1.2.1 and django version is 1.11

```
# corpmanage.conf
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    server unix:/home/corpmanage/corpmanage.sock; # for a file socket
    # server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}
# configuration of the server
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name mysite.com;
    server_name www.mysite.com;
    client_max_body_size 30m;

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /home/corpmanage/mediafiles;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/corpmanage/static-prod; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
     uwsgi_read_timeout 600;
    }
}
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen  443 ssl;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name mystic.com;
    server_name www.mysite.com;
    root /home/corpmanage;
    charset     utf-8;
    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 30m;

    ssl                  on;
    ssl_certificate      /root/.acme.sh/mystite.com/fullchain.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key  /root/.acme.sh/mysite.com/mysite.comkey;

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /home/corpmanage/mediafiles;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/corpmanage/static-prod; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
     uwsgi_read_timeout 600;
    }
}
```

Additionally I configured django settings as well

```
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'DENY'
```

When I do like this server return too many redirects.

I have tried all possible answers from internet.if someone types http: //mysite.com it should automatically redirect ot https: //mysite.com

Comment: nginx is supposed to do such redirects. [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#secure-ssl-redirect) is a nice comment about configuring SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT behind proxy starting with "_If turning this to True causes infinite redirects..._"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django's HttpResponseRedirect is http instead of https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41483068/djangos-httpresponseredirect-is-http-instead-of-https)